# How to copy an entire row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xslt

I need to create a form where I can include an "Add Row" button. Clicking this button should create a new row, which should be same as my last row. My row contains some drop down values too, so I want them to be appear the same in the next row.
(Edit: So i am able to clone a row but the id of each row is also getting cloned which i want to be unique).

```js
var regex = /^(.*)(\d)+$/i;
var cindex = 1;
$(document).on('click','.Buttons', function() {
    var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:first');
    var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
    cindex++;
    $clone.find(':input').val('');
    $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
    //update ids of elements in row
    $clone.find("*").each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 3) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cindex);
            }
    });
    $tr.after($clone);
});
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <tr>
    <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
    <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
    <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
    <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row0" name="row">
    <td>
      <select title="" tabindex="1" id="fldtype" name="fldtype" class="objselect">
        <option value="SEL" selected='true'>Select</option>
        <option value="GDS">Guides</option>
        <option value="LOF">Latest Offers</option>
        <option value="TEM">Templates</option>
        <option value="VID">Videos</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" class="objinputtext" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}">
      <xsl:attribute name="value"></xsl:attribute>
      </input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="15" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}">
      <xsl:attribute name="value"></xsl:attribute>
      </input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}">
      <xsl:attribute name="value"></xsl:attribute>
      </input>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="bottompanel">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</span>
<div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" onClick="fnAddMore ();" value="Add More" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: just get and set `html()`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/clone

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i tried using the clone method but isnt working for me. Can you please provide the part of code according to my code as I am totally new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Please show your code so we can help you debug it

Comment: Firstly, please use the `edit` link under the question to add information as code in comments is almost unreadable. Secondly, I meant the JS, not the HTML

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have updated something but this also doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're using has several issues, such as using the deprecated `delegate()` instead of `on()`, and also trying to delegate the event to an element which is not a parent of the target.

To achieve what you require you can use `clone()` to create a new instance of the first `tr` in the `table` which you can then `append()`. Note that I separated the headings and content of the table with `thead` and `tbody` elements to make retrieval and insertion easier. Finally, note that `input` elements do not have a closing tag, and there are several mismatched `</div>` and `</span>` tags which I removed from the HTML.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.Buttons', function() {
  var $clone = $('#dataTable tbody tr:first').clone().appendTo('#dataTable tbody');
  $clone.find(':input').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row0" name="row">
      <td>
        <select title="" tabindex="1" id="fldtype" name="fldtype" class="objselect">
          <option value="SEL" selected='true'>Select</option>
          <option value="GDS">Guides</option>
          <option value="LOF">Latest Offers</option>
          <option value="TEM">Templates</option>
          <option value="VID">Videos</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" class="objinputtext" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}" />
        <xsl:attribute name="value"></xsl:attribute>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="15" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}" />
        <xsl:attribute name="value"></xsl:attribute>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" class="objinputtext" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}" />
        <xsl:attribute name="value"></xsl:attribute>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="bottompanel">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<div class="buttonarea">
  <ul>
    <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add More" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking out your time and explaining the whole code. I really appreciate that.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Hello @Rory i was testing the code and find that whenever i click add button the values in the field ('Description','Image','URL') is also getting copied in the new row.I want the new Row to be completely blank. Please suggest me for the same. Thanks

Comment: You need to clear their values. I updated the answer to show you how

Comment: Yea got it. Thank you so much again :)